# Is there a twitter search widget operator for filtering on language?

Tags: twitter

I'm using code from http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search
Everything works fine, except I would like to filter the tweets by language.

So something like:

```
new TWTR.Widget({
 version: 2,
 type: 'search',
 search: 'rainbow',
 lang: 'en'
})
```

Is there an operator that serves that kind of functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an operator `lang:`. ie. https://twitter.com/#!/search/lang%3Ako You can use it in your search keyword but not as a widget option.

Your code you be something like:

```
new TWTR.Widget({
 version: 2,
 type: 'search',
 search: 'rainbow lang:ja'
})
```